# Why does when the GUI closes, a random window gets activated isntead of the most recently active window?

Tags: autohotkey

I launch the GUI but as soon as it closes my file manager is then activated, instead of the PDF-Xchange window.
I also tested it on my code editor, VsCode, same issue. As soon as the  GUI exits, the file manager is activated.

[image]

I have reduced the script down to the minimum lines needed to reproduce the issue, I dont have any other scripts running or any automation utilities.

It still keeps happening though. Once the GUI window exits, instead of activating the previous window, some random window is activated:

```
Return
RButton::
PDFX_()
KeyWait, RButton
Return

PDFX_(){
    static
        Gui Main:New,+AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, PDFX_PropPropWin
        Gui Main:Add,Edit           , vvCONstrkWidth Center x+4 y04 w80 Disabled, %  State.Width
        Gui Main:Show, x300 y300 w550 h40
        Sleep, 1500
        Gui Main:Hide                                      
        Gui Main:Submit,NoHide  
}
```

If I further reduce the lines, by taking out of the function, the issue is still present:

```
RButton::
    Gui Main:New,+AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption +HwndMainHwnd, PDFX_PropPropWin
    Gui Main:Add,Edit           , vvCONstrkWidth Center x+4 y04 w80 Disabled, %  State.Width
    Gui Main:Show, x300 y300 w550 h40
    Sleep, 1500
    Gui Main:Hide                                      
    Gui Main:Submit,NoHide  
    Return
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @KJ hey thanks for your help. The following `Gui Main:Show, x300 y300 w550 h40 NA` worked for me.